# Browser hangs while upload heavy files

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i'm doing a PHP/Javasript file upload using the plugin jquery.form.js which basically uses XHR2 for upload. But while we upload the files the browsers basic functionalities like scrolling, clicking kind of functionalities are not working. So i am greatly confusing on how to fix this. Any help/suggestions on this would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the file you are uploading?

You might want to try a solution that is specifically designed for uploading files, such as [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

Comment: Hi Justin, it is maximum upto 6 MB each. If i try to upload 10 files of 6 MB each it hangs like that.

Comment: That's a fair amount of network traffic... is it an option to use (or at least test out) another method of uploading the files?